# Is the dba_transformations dictionary view only accessible when you log in AS SYSDBA?

Tags: oracle, privileges, data-dictionary

I'm trying to query the data dictionary to find information on the transformations in the database. I've given my user DBA privileges, so I can access the DBA_ dictionary views. With this user, I can access all the DBA_ views without issues, however it seems I can only access DBA_TRANSFORMATIONS when logged in AS SYSDBA. Am I missing a special privilege to access this view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DBA_TRANSFORMATIONS does not have a public synonym by default.

Try this:

```
select *
from sys.DBA_TRANSFORMATIONS;
```

Comment: +1 for jva's answer - also noting here that Oracle has left out a few other synonyms for DBA views - you can see them by:  select view_name from dba_views
where owner = 'SYS'
and view_name like 'DBA%'
minus
select synonym_name from dba_synonyms
where owner = 'PUBLIC'